# Create URL for CActiveForm from within a widget inside a module

Tags: php, url, yii

I am writing a module for my site that will manage the Users. So in order to simplify my code, I wrote a "LoginWidget" view and made it accessible thru an actual derived class from  `CWidget`. Now I want to create an URL to the module. For now, I wrote it with the module ID typed in: `$this->controller->createUrl("/user/user/login");`. But how can I make it more "dynamic"? Let's say I changed the folder name from `user` to `users`. What code do I need to use to create an URL, that is relative to the module in which the widget is saved to?

I am using the latest Yii 1.1.x release.